# $E[X_2 | X_1] $ on Gaussian (as the best predictor)

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expected-value, conditional-probability, gaussian

$X_1, X_2 $ are jointly Gaussian.

For Gaussian, $E[X_2 | X_1] = E^L[X_2 | X_1]$ with mean zero $X_2, X_1$, where $E^L[Y|X=x] = W^*x - b^*$ and $W^*, b^* =\text{argmin}_{W,b} |Y-WX-b|$.

How do that show it is the case for $E[X_2 | X_1] = E^L[X_2 | X_1]$?

Comment: By the current formulation, wouldn't $W^*$ and $b^*$ be random and not constant?

Comment: Is $(X_1,X_2)$ a binormal distributed random variable? If so, the best appraximation is given by $a X_2$ for some constant which can be estimated by integration.

Comment: $(X_1, X_2) $ are jointly Gaussian